# Can I use a multicategory classification to solve XOR function using a perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am confused regarding why a perceptron with multicategory classification e.g, having three inputs and two output units (no hidden layer) can not be used to solve an XOR problem? Can it be?

Also, I implemented a perceptron with three input units and one output unit using a sigmoid activation function, and it seems to learn the XOR function. But the literature seems to say that this is not possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you says "three inputs", one of them is the bias input, right? And when you say it seems to learn XOR, does it do so consistently, with weights randomized differently each time?

Answer (score 0):

In short:

> I am confused regarding why a perceptron with multicategory
>   classification e.g, having three inputs and two output units (no
>   hidden layer) can not be used to solve an XOR problem? Can it be?

What do you mean by two output neurons? As an effect you get two output signals, for example

```
0 0 -> 0 1 
1 0 -> 0 0
0 1 -> 0 0
1 1 -> 1 0
```

Can you use it to represent xor? Yes, you can build **another model** on top of it and classify `0 0` to one class and `0 1` and `1 0` to another, but this would be equivalent of creating a **hidden layer**. In other words - what you are trying to do is actually exactly the same what hidden layers are doing. You are looking for some intermediate representation which makes problem easier - however this representation itself is not a solution. You need one more layer of abstraction.

> Also, I implemented a perceptron with three input units and one output
>   unit using a sigmoid activation function, and it seems to learn the
>   XOR function. But the literature seems to say that this is not
>   possible. Am I missing something?

No, you did not achieve this. It is simply impossible to represent a XOR function as a single layer hidden layer network - in fact activation function of output neuron does not have **any** effect on separation capability. If you provide a code, one can show you the error, for now - you can only be sure that you have done an error in at least one of the following:

- preparing the data, your dataset is not XOR problem (what is your third input? It can **only** be some constant value - so called bias, otherwise it is not XOR)
- processing data, you are not actually using single perceptron
- evaluation - your method is actually unable to learn XOR but your evaluation shows the opposite.